# Изменение значений DataGridView, при сортировке в WindowsForm

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, datagridview

Есть следующий код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)//Прохожу по таблице в поиске выделенных ячеек
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1[i, j].Selected == true)
                {
                    list2.AddLast(dataGridView1[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in list2)//Меняю значения на ок
        {
            cell.Value = "ok";
        }
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

По нажатию на кнопку, я прохожу по все DataGridView в поиске ячеек, чей Selected == true.
После добавляю их в LinketList list2.
После, через foreach по коллекции и меняю value на "ок"
Проблема в том, что если не сортировать DataGridView по нажатию на заголовок, то все выделенные ячейки меняют свое значение. Но, если отсортировать DataGridView  по нажатию на заголовок столбца, значения ячеек перестают корректно меняться.
В чем может быть проблема?

P.S.: Так же пробовал получать коллекцию ячеек, через SelectedCells и через DataTable.Selcted() получать строку по первичному ключу выделенной ячейки и менять значение в этой строке на "ОК".
И это, тоже не сработало!

К тому же ,что в первом, что во втором случае иногда происходит System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException по индексу. По какому индексу и как можно выйти за предел индекса при коллекции существующих ячеек, я не понимаю.

```
dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            DataRow[] dw = dt.Select("Айди = " + dataGridView1[0, cell.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            dt.Rows[cell.RowIndex][dataGridView1.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex].Name.ToString()] = "OK";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделай так

```
static public class DataGridExtension 
    {
        static public List<DataGridViewCell> Cells(this DataGridView view) 
        {
            var rows = ((IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>)view.Rows);
            var result = new List<DataGridViewCell>();
            rows.ToList().ForEach(row => result.AddRange((IEnumerable<DataGridViewCell>)row.Cells));
            return result;
        }

        static public void SetCellValue(this DataGridView grid,  Func<DataGridViewCell, bool> condition, object value)
        {

            grid.Cells().ForEach(v => { if (condition(v)) v.Value = value; });
        }
    }


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.SetCellValue(c => c.Selected, "ОК");
}
```

Comment: Выдал исключение
System.InvalidCastException: "Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection" к типу "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow]"."

Comment: В связи с проблемами в IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>, переписал их на foreach, проблема осталась и если честно, отрабатывает, даже хуже(
без сортировки, все супер, а при сортировке все печально